# How to prevent Hazelcast to replicate data to other nodes?

Tags: java, networking, hazelcast

I tried the following with Hazecast 3.11

1.) Settings up node A that fills a IQueue (distributed hazelcast queue) with objects:

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IQuery<String> configs = hazelcastInstance.getQueue("configs");
configs.add("foo");
```

2.) Joined node A with a second node B and accessing the shared queue which returns the stored value from node A

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IQuery<String> configs = hazelcastInstance.getQueue("configs");
System.out.println(configs.poll());
```

3.)
Although I did set backup-count and async-backup-count to zero, hazelcast seems to replicate the content from node 1 to node 2. Why?

I tried it via a xml and a programmatic configuration:

```
        com.hazelcast.config.Config cfg = new com.hazelcast.config.Config();
        NetworkConfig network = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
        network.setPort(5701).setPortAutoIncrement(true).setPortCount(20);
        JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("172.105.65.xxx").setRequiredMember(null).setEnabled(true);
        cfg.getQueueConfig("configs").setBackupCount(0).setAsyncBackupCount(0);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation=
  "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="20">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>172.105.65.xxx</member> 
        </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>


    <queue name="configs">
        <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <backup-count>0</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>
    </queue>

</hazelcast>
```

Comment: Why do you think the queue configuration isn't being followed ? It works for me, set to 1 there's a backup, set to 0 there isn't.

Comment: Also, check your code...you've shown `IQuery<String> configs ` but this should be `IQueue<String> configs`... might be a cut&paste error is masking the problem.

Comment: No, it's IQueue of course. I tried to write tests for the backup strategy, but I'm not sure on what's actually blocked with synchronized backups. Let's say node A makes an insert operation on a distributed queue that is on node B? Is the next statement on node A, node B or on both nodes delayed until the backup is completed?

Comment: Can you log that as a separate question please,. it's off topic for the original question here.

Comment: The more important part here is your point (3). Why do you think content is replicated from Node 1 to Node 2 ? If the configuration is as posted this shound't occur (and doesn't for me).